# variable length two dimensional array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, mingw, variable-length-array

Why is this code compiling successfully, without any warning:

```
int m,n;
cin >> m >> n;
int arr[m][n];
```

[compiled with MinGW with Code::Blocks]

Shouldn't atleast one of m or n must be constant at compile-time ??
I've seen variable length arrays accepted but they were all one-dimensional. Why is this two dimensional also being accepted ??

Moreover this is also running totally fine:

```
int arr[m][n][p];
```

Comment: In code::Blocks Setting->Compiler...->Compiler Setting-> Mark Enable warning demanded by Strict ISO C and ISO C++  (-pedantic), then you should get two warning.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-standard GCC extension. Many other compilers like Visual C++ don't support [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

[LIVE DEMO](http://rextester.com/WPX55597)

Answer (score 0):

Array dimensions only have to be defined on initialisation. Let's say that the user enters `m = 4` and `n = 2`:

```
int arr[m][n];
```

...becomes...

```
int arr[4][2];
```

Voilà, the compiler has all the information it needs to initialise the array.

I think that this is what you are thinking of:

```
int arr[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};    // this code will fail
```

The compiler will only automatically detect array size for the first dimension.

```
int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};   // this code will work
```

Comment: AFAIK , standard c++ doesn't support Variable Length Array.

Answer (score -1):

Syntax of your code is correct by c++ consepts. But if you enter m or n less than zero or m*n more than about 10000, it will be exaption. That's why you write your code in try-catch like below:

```
int m,n;
cin >> m >> n;
try {
    int arr[m][n];
} catch (Exception e){
    cout << "Error";
}
```

Comment: standard c++ doesn't support Variable Length Array.